# How to get posthoc tests (Tukey HDS or similar) in Two-way ANCOVA

Tags: r, ancova, post-hoc

in R I would like to carry out posthoc tests for a two-way ANCOVA with three covariates. I've managed to do it for a one-way ANCOVA:

```
 #Example data
 set.seed(1)
 factor1 <- as.factor(c(rep(1,5), rep(2, 5)))
 factor2 <- as.factor(c(rep(c(1,2),5)))
 dv <- rnorm(n=10)
 cov1 <- rnorm(n=10)
 cov2 <- rnorm(n=10)
 cov3 <- rnorm(n=10)
 data <- data.frame(factor1, factor2, dv, cov1, cov2, cov3)

 # setting contrast
 contrasts(data$factor1) <- contr.sum(2)
 contrasts(data$factor2) <- contr.sum(2)

 ancova.model <- aov(dv ~ factor1 + cov1 + cov2 + cov3, data=data)
 Anova(ancova.model, type="III")

 postHocTest <- glht(ancova.model, linfct = mcp(factor1 = "Tukey"))
 summary(postHocTest)
```

For a 2-way ANCOVA I've tried:

```
 ancova.model <- aov(dv ~ factor1*factor2 + cov1 + cov2 + cov3, data=data)
 postHocTest2 <- glht(ancova.model, linfct = mcp(factor1*factor2 = "Tukey"))
 summary(postHocTest2)
```

But get this error message:

```
 Error: unexpected '=' in "postHocTest2 <- glht(ancova.model, linfct = mcp(factor1*factor2 ="
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **lsmeans** package handles multi-factor cases more easily

```
library("lsmeans")
ancova.lsm <- lsmeans(ancova.model, ~ factor1 | factopr2)
ancova.lsm   # estimates and CIs
pairs(ancova.lsm)      # pairwise comparisons of factor1 for each factor2
pairs(ancova.lsm, by = "factor1")   # pairwise with roles reversed
pairs(ancova.lsm, by = NULL)    # pairwise of all cell means
```